# Problem factorising a simple equation

Tags: factoring

I have to factorise the equation $x^2-y^2-z^2+2yz+x+y-z$.
.How do I do it?Please help.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E2-y%5E2-z%5E2%2B2yz%2Bx%2By-z

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the problem? Show us what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$x^2-y^2-z^2+2yz+x+y-z$$
$$=x^2-(y-z)^2+x+y-z$$
$$=(x+y-z)(x-y+z)+(x+y-z)$$
$$=(x+y-z)(x-y+z+1)$$